# Symfony2 request called twice

Tags: symfony, firefox, symfony-2.3

I have a problem with Symfony2 duplicating requests.

The example controller below *should* just return a transparent gif. However, when the URL is requested there are two 'hits' to the request and doSomething() is called **twice** instead of once.

```
// simple action in a controller, ends up being called twice
public function testAction() {
    doSomething();

    $response = new Response(base64_decode('R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAOrq6gAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=='));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'image/gif');
    return $response;
}
```

If I change the response line so it sets a blank response then this stops happening (i.e. doSomething() is only called once):

```
// with a blank response it is only called once
public function testAction() {
    doSomething();

    $response = new Response('');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'image/gif');
    return $response;
}
```

If I remove the headers line then it's only called once:

```
// without the Content-Type header it is only called once
public function testAction() {
    doSomething();

    $response = new Response(base64_decode('R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAOrq6gAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=='));
    return $response;
}
```

Finally (here's the punchline)... if I change the Content-Type to text/html (or text/css) then it is only called once!

```
// if a text content type is used, it is only called once
public function testAction() {
    doSomething();

    $response = new Response(base64_decode('R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAOrq6gAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=='));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    return $response;
}
```

But with real content and the proper headers it is called twice (and two identical looking entries appear in the web profiler). The same problem also happens if a php template is used to render the content (I haven't tried with twig).

What could be causing this and how can it be prevented (or worked around)?

---

Edit: So, in summary, it was a Firefox bug and nothing to do with Symfony at all.

Comment: Taking a stab here.. `return $response->send()->getContent();` help? The idea being you need to send the headers. Then return the response. You may need `getContent` to prevent the headers from being printed in the response.

Comment: Nice idea but that doesn't help... still gets a double hit!

Comment: I would use the profiler, app/log/dev.log, or a debug_backtrace to find the source of those extra calls. You could throw a file_put_contents in the controller to help narrow it down as those logs can be quite verbose. If all else fails... `die($response->send()->getContent());` lol

Comment: In the dev.log the TEXT and GIF versions look the same right down to the final `[2014-06-24 15:48:39] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []` line. It's just that the GIF version then starts up another (identical looking) request after the first one terminates...

Comment: ...and the "if all else fails" idea doesn't work either. The first response is killed but then the second one triggers anyway.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is not with the controller or Symfony then. A die stops all execution. Nothing else would be called after that point. Perhaps the application/code loading this gif is loading it twice?

Comment: Hmm... maybe Firefox is calling it twice. Will experiment a bit with that.

Comment: I think you've got it. They're only being called once from Chrome. Thanks for the different angle!

Comment: Network tab in developer tools with preserve logs should show you the source of the phantom subsequent calls. Good luck, long life.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=583351

Comment: I just came back to post that link, but you beat me to it :) https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=583351